# Source for comparison of garbage companies sustainability efforts?

Tags: recycling, waste

I am looking for a source for info on how effective their recycling programs are, how much gas they use based on spread of trucks to garages, their greening efforts etc.  I live in New York, so even hearing about California or Germany would be useful as a comparison to motivate me to suggest changes locally.

Comment: Would hearing about a part of central Queensland's efforts be relevant to your research?

Comment: Sure, but I am hoping for a way to compare many different regions efforts.

Comment: ah okay, no worries

Answer (score 1):

I found a report from the German Municipal Solid Waste (MSW) management system. Here are some of their achievements:

- Recycling has increased from 48 % of MSW generated in 2001 to 62 % in 2010;
- The EU target for 50 % recycling by 2020 has therefore already been met;
- There was no increase in the recycling level of MSW between 2006 and 2010, whereas incineration has increased;
- The 2016 target for biodegradable municipal waste sent to landfill was met in 2006;
- There is a long tradition of national waste strategies and waste management plans in the federal states;
- A ban on landfilling un-pretreated MSW, producer responsibility and a focus on separate collection have proven to be important policy initiatives; and
- The latest initiative is the introduction of the so-called recycling bin that aims to increase recycling of plastics and metals from households, and mandatory separate collection of bio-waste by 2015.
- They have also had a net reduction of MSW from 2006-2010.

Here is the link. I'm on a mobile device so I don't know if it will display properly.

http://www.eea.europa.eu/publications/managing-municipal-solid-waste/germany-municipal-waste-management